# Razor MVC get single item from Model

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm very new to Razor/MVC stuff, so I have a very basic question.

I know that I can loop through a model in my partial view as such

```
@foreach (var e in Model.Modelname)
{
    e.ModelProperty
}
```

What I would like to do is instead of looping through all the items in the model as above, just get one (or the first one if there are more than one) item from the model.

I realize I could write something like this:

```
@foreach (var e in Model.Modelname)
{
    e.ModelProp.First()
}
```

However it seems silly to have to write a loop just to get 1 item from a model..and before anyone says why don't you just write

```
      e.ModelProp
```

Because quite often, I need to get the properties in a model, and I will get a completely different set of properties (and usually much more comprehensive) between  writing

```
 Model.ItemProp    

 or

  foreach (var e in Model.Modelname)
  {
      e.ItemProp
  }
```

So I guess what I'm really asking is how do I get those individual properties like I can get with var e in Model.Modelname without having to loop through the model?

I've tried stuff like

```
var e = Model.Modelname;

e.ModelProp
```

but obivously that doesn't work

thanks!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with real classes and real property names. Your attempt to make it more generic alas makes it harder to answer.

Comment: This depends entirely on what object you've passed in your controller to your view. (i.e. What type is `Model`?)

Comment: Instead of passing an `enumerable` of objects to your controller (in your view model), you should just return the object that you want to represent. Then there will be nothing to loop through.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written a more complete example. Was trying to make it generic as it was the concept I am stuck on, but you're right, a real world example might have been more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your trying to get the first item of Modelname and then the first property of that first item from Modelname:

```
Model.Modelname.First().ModelProp.First()
```

If you just want the first object in Modelname and then a specific property:

```
Model.Modelname.First().ModelProp
```

Little addition. The list might be empty, so add null checks:

```
Model.Modelname.FirstOrDefault()?.ModelProp ?? ""
```

Comment: It's just that easy huh? Dang, my bad. ha ha. Although sometimes (a lot of the time actually), I'll get the red squiggly when I have attempted to use .First()... does something need to be set in the controller to enable use of First?

Comment: @Nick No.  It's just plain C#. It's an extension method, so you must import the proper namespace (System.Linq in this case) in the class where you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get ALL the first items of ModelProp then

```
Model.Modelname.Select(x=> x.ModelProp.FirstOrDefault())
```

If you want to get the first ModelProp of the first ModelName:

```
Model.Modelname.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ModelProp.FirstOrDefault())
```